# Difference between Function and Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), functions inherit from `Function` and `Function` from `Function.prototype` in turn:

> The global `Function` object has no methods or properties of its own, however, since it is a function itself it does inherit some methods and properties through the prototype chain from `Function.prototype`.

What's the point of `Function.prototype` then? Why not move its properties to `Function` and let `Function.prototype` be `undefined`? Functions would be derived from `Function` instead.

Same goes for `Object` etc.

Comment: I would imagine it is because prototype properties are shared between all instances, unlike instance properties which are local to each instance.

Comment: > "Functions would be derived from Function instead".  Believe this is your source of confusion. Not sure where exactly you've read that, but Functions cannot be derived from Functions in a prototypical sense.

Comment: @nikc.org Alright, but why from `Function.prototype`? Or aren't the properties really inherited if we do `f.prototype = Function`, where `f` is a function? I mean, if you want to inherit from a function you do `f.prototype = super_f` and not `f.prototype = super_f.prototype`, right?

Comment: @Geert-Jan I'm reading "JavaScript: The Good Parts." Can't you have a random object as a prototype?

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> functions inherit from `Function`

You are quoting MDN loosely. What it actually says is:

> function objects inherit from `Function.prototype`

Note that on the MDN page, the initial word "function" in the above sentence is capitalized, but only because it is at the beginning of the sentence, not because it is referring to the JS object `Function`. It is referring to regular old functions declared as `function() { }`.

Remember that MDN is written by mere mortals. I would prefer they did not use the words "inherit" and "inheritance", not to mention "derived". JS does not have the concept of inheritance in the strict sense of the word. If you use this terminology, you will end up confusing yourself. What JS has is prototypes associated with objects. When accessing a property on an object, if it is not found, the prototype is consulted. If not found there, since a prototype is also an object with a prototype, the prototype's prototype is consulted, and so on up the chain.

Therefore, the above sentence would better be written as "function objects **have as their prototype** `Function.prototype`".

The JS `Function` object is not directly associated with `Function.prototype`, other than the fact that `Function.prototype` is a property of `Function`, and, since the `Function` object is itself a function, it itself has `Function.prototype` as its prototype. Whatever properties may or may not be present on `Function`, or hung on it by you, have nothing to do with the prototype chain and are not "inherited" by anyone.

When you do `(function() { }).call()`, the `call` property/method is first looked up on the function object itself; if it does not exist there, as it normally would not, then it is looked up on the prototype assigned intrinsically when the function was declared, which is `Function.prototype`. Where else would you put methods such as `call` or `apply` if not on `Function.prototype`? What else would you call the prototype automatically assigned to functions other than `Function.prototype`?

As an aside, note that `Function.call` will resolve correctly to the internal `call` function. Why? Not because that is where `call` lives, or because that is from where regular functions "inherit" `call`, but rather because, since as I mentioned before, `Function` is itself a function, and therefore has the prototype `Function.prototype`, `call` can be found on its prototype chain.

> What's the point of `Function.prototype` then? Why not move its properties to `Function` and let `Function.prototype` be undefined? Functions would be derived from `Function` instead.

`X.prototype` is a property on X used as the prototype for objects created using X as a constructor. Therefore, to assign the correct prototype to objects created using `Function` as a constructor (which includes functions declared as `function x() { }`), the prototype must be present as the `prototype` property on `Function`.

Comment: Crap, totally forgot `Function.prototype` is just a property, not a seperate object. Anyway, why not move the properties of the object referenced by `Function.prototype` into `Function`? If you have two functions, `f` and `g`, then you'd say `f.prototype = g` and not `f.prototype = g.prototype`, right? And concerning "it itself has Function.prototype as its prototype" - wouldn't that result in an infinite recursive loop? And building upon that, when does the compiler stop climbing up the prototype chain?

Comment: No, because the prototype of `Function.prototype` is `Object.prototype`. The engine stops climbing the prototype chain when it encounters an object without a prototype. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) == null`.

Comment: So, `Function.prototype.prototype === Object.prototype`? And doesn't " it itself has Function.prototype as its prototype." mean that `Function.prototype === Function.prototype`? Yes, that's obviously true but I don't understand it anyway. :(

Comment: You're confusing `X.prototype`, which is a property on X which is used as the prototype for objects constructed with X as the constructor, with the prototype of X, which can be obtained with `Object.getPrototypeOf(X)`, or `X.__proto__` if you prefer.

Comment: After some research I got the concept of prototypes now. That's what I have: Every object has an invisible property `__proto__`, which apes class inheritance. `prototype` is just a template for `__proto__`. I've only read about its use paired with the `new` keyword, though. Does that all also apply to, like `var f = function() { }`? And the only canonical resource I have is "JavaScript: The Good Parts." If possible, could you tell me why I didn't grasp the concept immediately despite reading that , yeah, pretty much "standard" book? Except my own incapability to get it, of course.

Comment: Yes, normally `X.prototype` is applied as the prototype to objects created using `new X()`, but `Function.prototype` is applied as the prototype to "literal" function syntax--`function() { }`, just as `Object.prototype` is applied as the prototype to literal object syntax such as `{}`, `RegExp.prototype` is applied as the prototype to literal regular expressions such as `/x/`.

Answer (score 2):

Functions on the prototype are only created once and shared between each instance. Functions created in the constructor are created as new objects for each new object created with the constructor.

As a general rule functions should be on the prototype since they will generally not be modified for different objects of the same type, and this has a slight memory/performance benefit. Other properties like objects and arrays should be defined in the constructor, unless you want to create a shared, static property, in which case you should use the prototype.

Its easier to see the distinctions with normal objects or arrays rather than functions

```
function Foo(){
  this.bar = [];
}
var fooObj1 = new Foo();
var fooObj2 = new Foo();

fooObj1.bar.push("x");
alert(fooObj2.bar) //[]
as opposed to:

function Foo(){
}

Foo.prototype.bar = []
var fooObj1 = new Foo();
var fooObj2 = new Foo();

fooObj1.bar.push("x");
alert(fooObj2.bar) //["x"]
```

Comment: This is all true, but not really what the OP was talking about, which is the inheritance structure for functions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Function.prototype` for if you want to extend functions, consider this:

```
Function.prototype.moo = 5;
function x() { };
console.log(x.moo); // 5
```

every function you make now has the property `moo`, versus:

```
Function.quack = 6;
function b() {};
console.log(b.quack); // undefined
```

This is not true if you just slap a property onto `Function`. Every function DOES NOT inherit properties assigned to `Function`, which is why you need `Function.prototype`.